# jQuery surround highlighted text with SPAN

Tags: jquery, replace, highlight

The following code is supposed to surround the highlighted text in a given Div with a span.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.format').click(function(){
       var highlight = window.getSelection();

        var spn = '<span class="highlight">' + highlight + '</span>';
        $('.conttext').content().replace(highlight, spn);

    });
});
```

A function of this nature could be used to provide formating options to an HTML contenteditable DIV.

Something is clearly wrong though as it does not currently work.

http://jsfiddle.net/BGKSN/20/

Comment: .replace doesn't work on an array-like object unless you specifically define it as a method of that object. .content() also doesn't exist. did you check the console?

Answer (score 11):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/BGKSN/24/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.format').click(function(){
        var highlight = window.getSelection();  
        var spn = '<span class="highlight">' + highlight + '</span>';
        var text = $('.conttext').text();
        $('.conttext').html(text.replace(highlight, spn));
    });
});
```

**Later Edit**:

Based on the comment, this is the real functional example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BGKSN/40/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.format').click(function(){
        var highlight = window.getSelection(),  
        spn = '<span class="highlight">' + highlight + '</span>',
        text = $('.conttext').text(),
        range = highlight.getRangeAt(0),
        startText = text.substring(0, range.startOffset), 
        endText = text.substring(range.endOffset, text.length);

        $('.conttext').html(startText + spn + endText);
    });
});
```

**Docs**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getSelection

Comment: Very nice! However, it will only replace the first instance of matching text in the document.  If you select one of the instances of 'it' for example, the first one will always get the span added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, you had your html wrong, something like this
`<a href="" class="format">test</div>`

<s>Secondly, when you tried to click test it deselected the selected text because this is what happens if you click somewhere when you have some text selected. So, with this in mind, I changed it to `$("body").keypress()` so it will wrap the highlighted text in span when a key is pressed. Also, fixed some of the jQuery code and voila, it works!</s>

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BGKSN/23/).

If you fix your anchor tag and your jQuery a bit
`$(".contenttext").contents()` where `.contents()` is a non-existand function to
 `$(".contenttext").html($(".contenttext").html().replace(highlight, spn));`
it works as expected as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BGKSN/25/).

Comment: Very nice! However, it will only replace the first instance of matching text in the document. If you select one of the instances of 'it', for example, the first one will always get the span added to it.