# Upper case a selection of text in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, uppercase, getselection

I'm getting an `undefined is not a function` error when I try and run the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textarea").select(function() {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        $("#upper").click(function() {
            // alert(selection);
            var upper = selection.toUpperCase();
            var text = $("#textarea").text();
            $("#textarea").html(text.replace(selection, upper));
        });
    }); 
});
```

I'm trying to select text from a textarea, and click a button to make the selection uppercase. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8syb2d8j/1/) of the complete code.

Comment: the jsfiddle is very different from the code here - and also has syntax errors.. which is it?

Comment: Apologies, the link has been updated.

Comment: Your first link was actually less-broken. You now have nested event handlers (usually a very bad sign).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getSelection` returns an object. You need to call `toString()` on it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selection;
    $("#textarea").select(function () {
        selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    });
    $("#upper").click(function () {
        if (selection) {
            var upper = selection.toUpperCase();
            var text = $("#textarea").text();
            $("#textarea").html(text.replace(selection, upper));
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/8syb2d8j/4/

**Notes:**

- *your event handlers were nested (usually a bad idea)*
- I added a check to ensure that there is a selection before trying to upppercase it.
- as, potentially, the text you highlight may occur more than one, using `replace` is actually not a great solution. Try highlight the second `i` and see what I mean. You should use the properties of the selection object instead to work out the exact part of the string that was selected,

After browsing around for portable solutions, I found the [jQuery TextRange plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/textrange/), which, based on [the demo](http://dwieeb.github.io/jquery-textrange/) is more than enough for this problem.

Comment: Thanks. The nesting was because I thought my error had something to do with variable scope!

Comment: @mpdc: Nah, just move the variable back a level. Please note the problem I have noted at the end. You may want to rethink how you do this. :)

Comment: I'm looking at the second answer here for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836488/jquery-surround-highlighted-text-with-span :) Thanks.

Comment: That is a good example. Use the `range` properties provided by `getSelection()`

Comment: Just been browsing around the options for doing it "properly" (i.e. using selection ranges) and there is a lot *noise* out there. Browser compatibility *will* be an issue.