# How to wrap text that crosses node boundaries in span(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, word-wrap

I would like to apply a style, such as a yellow background, to the text that a user selects on my webpage. Unfortunately, the selected text may cross node boundaries (e.g. it may begin in the middle of one div and end in the middle of another div).

What is the best way to wrap a span (or multiple spans) around all of the selected text?

**Set up**

```
<div>This sentence is not selected. THIS SENTENCE </div>
<div>IS SELECTED. This sentence is not selected.</div>
```

**Desired result**

```
<div>This sentence is not selected. <span>THIS SENTENCE</span> </div>
<div> <span>IS SELECTED.</span> This sentence is not selected.</div>
```

Here are two similar questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6328718), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17836488)) restricted to the case when the selection does not cross node boundaries.

Comment: Check this answer.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437769/javascript-how-to-divide-selected-text-along-multiple-p-tags-into-each-content/52438315#52438315](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437769/javascript-how-to-divide-selected-text-along-multiple-p-tags-into-each-content/52438315#52438315)

Answer (score 0):

Only Firefox allows multiple ranges per selection.
All other browsers are limited to one range with `getSelection()`.

Answer (score -1):

To apply a style  i would suggest not missing up with your html, instead you can use this :

```
::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

Anyway , the problem will be that you can only change the `color` and the `background` CSS properties.

More information about this technique can be found here :
https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Comment: This does not satisfy my requirements because the text needs to be styled even after the user deselects the text.