# Javascript: How to divide selected text along multiple p tags into each content for each tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wonder that selected text along multiple p tags can be divided into each content for each tag. For example,

```
<p>I am (selection start)a boy</p>
<p>You are(selection end) a girl</p>
```

I would like to divide like "a boy" and "You are".

Also for three p tags,

```
<p>I am (selection start)a boy</p>
<p>You are a girl</p>
<p>We are(selection end) friends</p>
```

I would like to obtain three elements, "a boy", "You are a girl", "We are".

Is it possible for Chrome using javascript?

Thanks you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
document.onmouseup=function(){
    var selected = document.getSelection().toString()
    var data=selected.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "\n").split("\n").filter(Boolean)
    var dataWithSpan=data.map((x,y)=>`<span>${x}</span>`);
    console.log(data)
    console.log(dataWithSpan)
}
```

```html
select from the following paragraps
<p>I am a boy</p>
<p>You are a girl</p>

select from the following paragraps
<p>I am a boy</p>
<p>You are a girl</p>
<p>We are friends</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried this, but it does not show any result.

Comment: Does it depend on browser?

Comment: Wait I do some change

Comment: I have one more question! Is it possible to wrap each divided string by span tag? I want to change the style of each selected string. I tried it using jquery filter or contain method, but I cannot handle it.

Comment: Yes this is. Do this : -  ```var dataWithSpan=data.map((x,y)=>`<span>${x}</span>`)```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not show any change. Do I need another script for that?

Comment: I think I am not ready to catch up your help:( Could you explain more in detail? I hope it does not bother you.

Comment: You want each selected string in span I have added that using map function. Not clear what you want

Comment: Sorry for confusion. What I want to do is that when I select some text, I get each string splitted by p tag like my original question, and then wrap each string by a span tag to change its style.

Comment: But that should be different question because when users comes at this platform He looks into this question and don't see comments

Comment: It will be confusing for user to understand if he have same problem

Comment: Please ask different question regarding this

Comment: I got it. Since your previous comment was very fruitful to me, I asked another question here. Please understand my immaturity.