# Javascript: How to wrap selected text along multiple p tags into each content for each tag with span tag

Tags: javascript

When I select text along multiple p tags, I obtain each content for each tag, which was answered in [Javascript: How to divide selected text along multiple p tags into each content for each tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437769/javascript-how-to-divide-selected-text-along-multiple-p-tags-into-each-content/52438315#52438315).

For example,

```
<p>I am (selection start)a boy</p>
<p>You are a girl</p>
<p>We are(selection end) friends</p>
```

Now, I can obtain three elements, "a boy", "You are a girl", "We are".

Then, how to wrap each element by span tag and change its style? For example,

```
<p>I am (selection start) <span style ="font-weight:bold">a boy</span></p>
<p><span style ="font-style:italic">You are a girl</span></p>
<p><span style ="font-decoration:underline">We are</span> (selection end) friends</p>
```

I tried this using jquery wrapinner method, filter, contain and so on, but I could not figure it out.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you use Jquery or only Javascript?

Comment: I try to use both!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.replace('a boy','<span style="font-weight: bold">a boy</span>');
    elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.replace('You are a girl','<span style="font-weight: bold">You are a girl</span>');
    elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.replace('We are','<span style="font-weight: bold">We are</span>');
}
```

```html
<p>I am a boy</p>
<p>You are a girl</p>
<p>We are friends</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your validation to choose where to add your `span`, but since you can use Jquery you can get your solution with this code:

```js
$("#p1").html($("#p1").html().replace("a boy", '<span style ="font-weight:bold">$&</span>'));
$("#p2").html($("#p2").html().replace("You are a girl", '<span style ="font-style:italic">$&</span>'));
$("#p3").html($("#p3").html().replace("We are", '<span style ="text-decoration:underline">$&</span>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">I am (selection start)a boy</p>
<p id="p2">You are a girl</p>
<p id="p3">We are(selection end) friends</p>
```

**Note:** Also its not `font-decoration:underline` its `text-decoration:underline`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 3 paragraph like below :

```
<p id="p1">I am (selection start)a boy</p>
<p id="p2">You are a girl</p>
<p id="p3">We are(selection end) friends</p>
```

Then you can change style and wrap with any html tag like this :

```
let p1 = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
let p2 = document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML;
let p3 = document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = `<span style='color:blue'>${p1}</span>`
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = `<span style='color:green'>${p2}</span>`
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = `<span style='color:darkGray'>${p3}</span>`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/5Lonrk0f/4/

Comment: I want to change the selected text only, so your answer is out of scope though. Thank you for your answer!